# Select a node that has a specific attribute value in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

In that XML :

```
<elements>
        <product id="1">
                <brand>xxxxxxx</brand>
                <dci>xxxxx</dci>
                <therapeutic_area>xxxxxx</therapeutic_area>
        </product>
        <product id="2">
                <brand>xxxxxx</brand>
                <dci>xxxx</dci>
                <therapeutic_area>xxxx</therapeutic_area>
        </product>
        <product id="3">
                <brand>xxx</brand>
                <dci>xxxx</dci>
                <therapeutic_area>xxxxx</therapeutic_area>
        </product>
```

I need to select the node which has a specific attribute value. For instance 2

I tried this but it does not work:

```
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product")[0].getAttributeNode("2"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: did you miss `</elements>` by parsing there or is it missing from the xml file?

Comment: No, i just forgot to copy/paste it in the code above, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var list=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
     if(list[i].getAttribute("id")==2){
        // Found your node
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmlfile = "<elements><product id=\"1\"><brand>xxxxxxx</brand><dci>xxxxx</dci><therapeutic_area>xxxxxx</therapeutic_area></product><product id=\"2\"><brand>xxxxxx</brand><dci>xxxx</dci><therapeutic_area>xxxx</therapeutic_area></product><product id=\"3\"><brand>xxx</brand><dci>xxxx</dci><therapeutic_area>xxxxx</therapeutic_area></product></elements>";

var parser = new DOMParser();

xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xmlfile,"text/xml");

var products = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("product");

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
    if (products[i].getAttribute("id") == 2) {
       // product id is 2.   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvgLhw66/
<-- working fiddle.

You are using the wrong prototype. getAttributeNode does not exist, you're looking for getAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
var node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (var index in node) {
    if (node[index].getAttribute("id") == "2") {
        alert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what your trying to do here, but try something like this.

```
alert(document.querySelector("[id='2']").querySelector('brand'));
```

see [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).